# useEffect can not removeEventListener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function HomeList(props) {
  const [{data,isLastPage}, setData] = useState({
      data: [],
      isLastPage: false
  });
  const getData = () => {
    flag = false;
    request("/api/app/recommend", {
      params: {
        list_code: props.listcode,
        page,
        preview: 0
      }
    }).then(res => {
      let tmp = (res.msg === "lastpage" || isLastPage) ? true : false;
      if(tmp) {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", hd);
      }
      setData(data => ({data:data.data.concat(res.data),isLastPage:tmp}));
      flag = true;
    });
    page++;
  };

  const onScroll = () => {
    const target = window.document.documentElement;
    const offsetH = target.offsetHeight;
    const scrollH = target.scrollHeight;
    const triggerH = scrollH * 0.5;
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    //滚动过页面高度一半加一屏高度后加载数据
    if (scrollH - offsetH - scrollTop < triggerH) {
      if (flag) {
        getData();
      }
    }
  };

  const hd = throttle(onScroll, 500);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    window.addEventListener("scroll", hd);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", hd);
      page = 1;
      flag = true;
    };
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
      //here !!!!!!!!!!!!
      if(data.length < 18 && data.length > 0 && !isLastPage) {
          getData();
      }
  },[data])
```

I want to remove scroll eventListener when the api msg is 'lastpage',
but react hooks create a new function hd in each `useEffect`. If lastpage 
in `useLayoutEffect` change, `removeEventListener` does not work.

Comment: What does mean *not work* - it just doesn't remove listener or do you get some error? If the latter, post error message

Comment: Please use English all the time. Please don't include Chinese comments in your code. Otherwise people who want to help you don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will need to listen to changes on `isLastPage` and we going to add the event listener only when `isLagePage` is false

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isLastPage) {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scroll);
  }
  return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', scroll);
}, [isLastPage]);
```

Comment: Would it make sense to add the `if` check in the return statement as well?

Comment: in the return statement, islastpage first value is false,so it will not run removeEventListener.

Comment: finally I write like this, and it's work ```return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", hd);
    };```

Comment: @孙方斌 You right `useEffect` capture the dependencies and we should check if it isn't the last because that's when its going to get changed.